# Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)

Tags: raspbian, linux, debian

I'm trying to execute the command `sudo apt-get -y install linux-headers-rpi` to install this driver for a pm sensor. However, my raspi gives me this output every time when I execute this command:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

I've searched through other post on the forum, and they said that it should be ok once I've reboot it or killed the process that's occupying the file. I did it, but it didn't work. Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First check if there is a `dpkg` process running, `ps afx|grep dpkg`.

If thats the case, kill it with `sudo killall dpkg`.

Remove the lock file with `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock`

That should do the trick.

Comment: So I first checked if there are any processes running: ps afx|grep dpkg. Result: '18271 pts/0    S+     0:00              \_ grep --color=auto dpkg'. Then I removed the lock file 'sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock'. Now it gives me this: 'E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?'

Comment: google "/var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied) E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root"

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem recently, and it turns out the issue was that I was only sudo-ing one of the chained commands I was using.

I was using `sudo apt-get update && apt-get install -y libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev build-essential`

But I should have been using `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev build-essential`

(note the second `sudo`)

Answer (score 1):

sometimes the error message gives you the pointer to the problem.
`"Are you root"` means you may be trying to run a command without superuser privilege. try running the command preceded with sudo e.g.
`sudo <command>`

Comment: Please notice that the OP tried the command: `sudo apt-get -y install linux-headers-rpi`.

Answer (score 0):

This one is old, but I recently had this problem with a freshly written iso.

Expanding the filesystem to use the entire SD card did the trick for me.

As `apt-get upgrade` might be quite expensive (counting storage). I assume this has been the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happen with me but finally it solved do :

```
ps afx|grep dpkg
sudo killall dpkg
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Run your process you want, if isn't work follow next step

```
apt --fix-broken install
```