# I'm getting an error when installing any package

Tags: raspbian, apt

I updated apt-get and tried to install tightvncserver using "sudo apt-get install tightvncserver" i got the error below

```
E:sub-process /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10 returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: try running `sudo apt-get update` first, then `sudo apt-get upgrade` before you install any package. Try that & let us know how it goes.  You should also read `man apt`

Comment: When i run the command **sudo apt-get upgrade** i get this error **E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)**\

Comment: Sounds like something got hung... `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` is a file apparently used to "lock" something to prevent two processes from working against each other. [This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process) implies that the lock file should ordinarily be absent, yet I see it on my system which is functioning normally. In other words, I'm not quite sure what is going on! If you haven't rebooted your system, please do that & try `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get full-upgrade`.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind (always) is that re-installing your system (starting from scratch) is often quicker and easier than troubleshooting these things. Not that they happen often, but I've spent hours and hours troubleshooting that I count as wasted time - not always as sometimes I learn something - but sometimes, I learn nothing. Anyway - something to ponder. Let us know what you see after trying the comment above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/79382/could-not-open-lock-file-var-lib-dpkg-lock-open-13-permission-denied)